# Enable Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts) option via Jenkinsfile.groovy

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to enable **"Enable Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)"** option and add Authentication Token via Jenkinsfile.groovy. Tried `pipelineTriggers([authenticationToken('jenkins')])` as per https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.WorkflowJob.authenticationToken but no luck. Please help me with some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to call it and what is the problem you are coming across? You should simply enable the remote build option, provide a secure token, then use the REST API to trigger the build with the URL `JENKINS_URL/job/stack/build?token=TOKEN_NAME`. You can also set the user it needs to build as when sending the API call. [Here](https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/jenkins-remote-build-trigger-url/) is a full tutorial on how to do this.

**EDIT**: If you want to do this with DSL, as far as I know the `authenticationToken` method won't work from Jenkins 1.7 onwards. You have to use [generic webhook trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger/) which allows you to trigger builds remotely with DSL. Examples can be found [here](https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger/#plugin-content-job-dsl-plugin).

Comment: No, I want to enable this option `Enable Trigger builds remotely` Via the pipeline script and not manually. I do not have issues with triggering the build.

Comment: Have edited the answer.